# TypeORM cascade: true flag does not delete related entities

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I can not figure out if it is me, of `cascade: true` option does not delete children entities when removing parent one?

```
@Entity()
export class Folder {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public readonly id: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Segment, (segment) => segment.folder, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  public segments: Segment[];
}


@Entity()
export class Segment {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public readonly id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Folder, (folder) => folder.segments)
  @JoinColumn()
  public folder: Folder;
}
```

and then I do

```
await getRepository(Folder).delete(id);
```

which gives me an error:

```
update or delete on table "folder" violates foreign key constraint "FK_12606f83d18e5ae0c7e5693f3fb" on table
"segment"
```

Also tried to do

```
const folder = await this.repository.findOneOrFail(id);
repository.remove(folder)
//or 
folder.segments = null;
await this.repository.save(folder);
```

still error...

I don't want to loop through all children entities and remove them manually. I thought `cascade: true` should handle it as well as saving or updating.
Maybe syntax supposes to be different?

Thanks!

Comment: add onDelete="CASCADE" on your orm foreign key

Answer (score 12):

*Cascade* only describes what to do with related entities, it doesn't have an effect when the entity itself is deleted. If you want to delete all segments when deleting a folder you need to use *onDelete* (this is a database feature, otherwise then cascade, which is implemented within TypeORM. This means you need to generate and execute migrations when adding onDelete). So this should work for you:

```
@Entity()
export class Segment {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public readonly id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Folder, (folder) => folder.segments, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn()
  public folder: Folder;
}
```

Comment: That is totally true, regarding onDelete: 'Cascade'. And I use this feature as well.
What I can not figure out - is for what reason they added 'remove' to cascade options? There suppose to be a reason and the way to use it.

Comment: I always thought the remove option allows you to remove relations. So you have a folder with two segments and then you set folder.segments = [] and afterwards save it (await this.repository.save(folder)), then TypeORM removes the relation, but keeps the segments. This is currently working, but when changing  cascading to "cascade: ['insert']", the delete behaviour still works, which I would no expect. So yeah, I can't tell you exactly what "cascade: ['remove']" does.

Comment: Yeah, interesting, btw. Why I did folder.segments = [] it was trying to remove relation, but keep segment item in DB. But in this case, there was a DB error like 'folder_id can not be null'. So probably need to implicitly set that segment entity can have orphans... 
Anyway, thank you for response.

Answer (score 5):

**Parent Entity** => set `cascade to "remove"`

```
// Parent Entity
@OneToMany(type => Comment, comment => comment.parent,{ cascade: ["remove"] })
replies: Comment[];
```

**Child Entity** =>  set `onDelete to CASCADE` and `orphanedRowAction to delete`.

```
// Child Entity
@ManyToOne(type => Comment, comment => comment.replies, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE", orphanedRowAction: 'delete'
})
parent: Comment;
```

##### Note

When you want to delete **Parent** with **its children** you have to do as follows:

```
await ParentRepository.delete(parentId)
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

***- Parent Entity***

```js
@OneToMany(type => Comment, comment => comment.parent, { cascade: ["remove"] })
replies: Comment[];
```

Create **cascade** option in **@OneToMany** relation.
**@OneToMany** relation onDelete option is not needed.

```js
{ cascade: ["remove"] }
```

***- Child Entity***

```js
@ManyToOne(type => Comment, comment => comment.replies, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
parent: Comment;
```

Create **onDelete** option in **@ManyToOne** relation.
**@ManyToOne** relation cascade option is not needed.

```js
{ onDelete: "CASCADE" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "bug" (not sure if it's the the desired behavior) inside the typeorm code, I fixed this issue by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package because I needed this fix asap

You need to patch the file at `node_modules/typeorm/persistence/subject-builder/OneToManySubjectBuilder.js` with this code (- is what you need to remove and + is what you need to add):

```
             var removedRelatedEntitySubject = new Subject_1.Subject({
                 metadata: relation.inverseEntityMetadata,
                 parentSubject: subject,
-                canBeUpdated: true,
+                canBeUpdated: !relation.isNullable,
+                mustBeRemoved: relation.isNullable,
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the TypeORM GitHub bug?

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2467 here