# How can I cascade delete with one-to-many relation in typeORM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have group and contact entities in OneToMany relationship. I add contacts within the group. When I want to delete, I want both sides of the database to be deleted. but only the group table is deleted.

here's `contact.entity`
[image: contact.entity]

**Here's one to many relationship:**

here's `group.entity`
[image: group.entity]

The function I wrote in the service is as follows:
[image: function in the service]

I tried many solutions by searching. Adding cascades on both sides, I know this isn't right, but I wanted to try, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key on the table `contact` that references the table `group` ? If yes then your foreign key must have `on delete cascade`

Comment: If what you mean is foreign key in the contact table, yes there is. GroupId foreign key is have. but there is no contact foreign key in the group table

Comment: Please add code to your question as text using the editor. Images of code are discouraged. They are harder to read, not possible to copy/paste code, poor for search engines etc...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718300/typeorm-cascade-true-flag-does-not-delete-related-entities/73933050#73933050

Answer (score 0):

you are using it wrong way.
If you hover to softDelete function, you will see it need props like: `(method) Repository<Group>.softDelete(criteria: string | number | Date | ObjectID | string[] | FindConditions<Group> | number[] | Date[] | ObjectID[]`
[image: hovered]

which mean you have to use it like :

```js
getRepository(Group).softDelete({ id: groupId})
```

same as update function:
[image: update]

```js
getRepository(Group).update({id: groupId}, {name: "new name"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard code something it can be done by the database itself. If you want all the contacts of the group to be deleted while the group is deleted then use foreign key with

> on delete cascade

eg:

```
create table group1(
id serial primary key,
name varchar
);

create table contact(
id serial primary key,
name varchar,
group_id integer references group1 (id) on delete cascade
);
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Q8HYq2tVUNJaQaLRsyo8r/0)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a softDelete, so you should add a `{ cascade: ['soft-delete'] }` option to the parent entity which in this case is `Group` being:

```
@OneToMany(Contact, (contact) => contact.group, { cascade: ['soft-delete'] })
contact: Contact[]
```

Just in case, `ON DELETE` constraint is database level based, `soft-delete` in other hand is code level based, so the ORM will trigger an `UPDATE` to change the time in the `deleted_at` column of your entities.

Having the above in mind, `cascade` option will configure how the ORM acts when a change is done in the parent entity (code level based), `onDelete` option will configure a constraint in the table (db level based)